# how do we insert column-based record in KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Iam using inline query to insert data to my table. Without using inline query, can we insert a column-based record. Using inline you have to enter all the column values, instead of it can we insert only one column value?

Comment: can you please provide sample/expected input output.

Comment: let's say I have an employee table with name,id,country,age columns. KQL query i use to insert is (.ingest inline into table emp  <| "sanjay",1234,"india",21) . Now i need to insert ID column values only. How to insert data based on column like in SQL(insert into emp (ID) values (4567) )

Comment: I dont want to use( .ingest inline into table emp <| "",1234,"")), If we have 10 columns we have to specify all the column values.  So i am looking for a way to insert data for a single column

Answer (score 1):

> insert single column-based record in KQL .

- using datatable I was able to achieve it

```
.show  databases
```

[image]

```
.create  table  Employee (Name:string, Id:int, Country:string, Age:int)
```

[image]

```
.set-or-replace  EmployeeTable <|
datatable(Name:string, Id:int, Country:string, Age:int)
[
"sanjay", 123, "india", 21,
"john", 456, "usa", 35,
"maria", 789, "france", 27
]
```

[image]

```
let newEmployeeTable = datatable (Id:int) [4567, 8901, 2345];

EmployeeTable

| union newEmployeeTable
```

[image]

Comment: after executing all the steps, when i query the EmployeeTable its not showing the ID records for 4567, 8901, 2345.

Comment: please check the if  table id and id: int is typed same

Comment: Its not inserting values into the table, values are appearing only in the result.

Comment: using 

```
.set-or-append EmployeeTable<| datatable (Name:string , Id:int, County:string, Age:int )[" ",1234," ",int(null)]

```

I able to (insert)[https://i.imgur.com/BpWKjCU.png) to (Id)

Comment: using .set-or-append  we have to mention all other column values, or else this command will not work.

Comment: yes, but by using ".set-or-append EmployeeTable<| datatable (Name:string , Id:int, County:string, Age:int )[" ",1234," ", int(null)]  "I was able to insert single column [value](https://i.imgur.com/BpWKjCU.png).

Comment: Still we have to specify the other column values as null, this will be problem when we have 10 or more columns

Comment: I am checking for other methods too.